# Differentiation of logarithm summation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, education

I am trying to compute the derivative of a logarithm sum:

$f(y) =log(\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n} y_i}{n})$

Y is a set of values of n values {$y_1,y_2,...,y_n$}

This is what I got so far, but I am not familiar with this kind of derivative, can it actually be done?

$\frac{df(y)}{dy}=\frac{1}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}y_i}$

Comment: Expand the logarithm and try for $n=2$

Comment: So it's $log\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}$

Comment: I still have no idea

Comment: What do you mean by taking the derivative with respect to a set of values (y)?